# Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://? - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Django. I'm making a data scraping project, I've made this code but facing problem to download the CSV file.
I used The function 'Download' in the file but not getting the desired result. Instead, I'm getting this error

`Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?`

Here is my code

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        url  = request.POST.get('url', '')

        down = request.POST.get('download','')

        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")
        p_name = soup.find_all("h2",attrs={"class": "a-size-mini"})
        p_price = soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class": "a-price-whole"})
        p_image = soup.findAll('img', {'class':'s-image','src':re.compile('.jpg')})

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="product_file.csv"'


        for name,price,image in zip(p_name,p_price,p_image):
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            row = writer.writerow([name.text, price.text,image['src']])

            name_data  = [data.text for data in p_name]
            price_data = [data.text for data in p_price]
            image_data = [data['src'] for data in p_image]
            dec = {'name':name_data, 'price':price_data, 'image':image_data}



        if down:
            return response



    else:
        dec = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html',dec)
```

When i remove this "if down:" it downloads my csv file correctly, when i keep the if condition it throws error :

`Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?`

index.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            <h1 class="mb-3 display-4">Amazone Scraper</h1>
            <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="URL" required autofocus>
            <button class="mt-3 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="submit" name='submit'>Scrap</button>
        </form>
        <p class="mt-3"><a href="upload">Upload</a> Your File For Updates Regarding</p>
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}<!--------download---------->
          <input class="mt-3 btn btn-info" type="submit" id="download" name='download' value='Download'/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probles is that you have two forms and when you click `download` button it sends data from second form which doesnt's contain `url` field. Because of this `url` value is empty in your view. You should refactor this view to use only one form.

Or you can try to add `url` field to second form and use `url` from fist one as default value:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            <h1 class="mb-3 display-4">Amazone Scraper</h1>
            <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="URL" required autofocus>
            <button class="mt-3 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="submit" name='submit'>Scrap</button>
        </form>
        <p class="mt-3"><a href="upload">Upload</a> Your File For Updates Regarding</p>
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}<!--------download---------->
```

You also need to add `url` to template context:

```
    for name,price,image in zip(p_name,p_price,p_image):
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        row = writer.writerow([name.text, price.text,image['src']])

        name_data  = [data.text for data in p_name]
        price_data = [data.text for data in p_price]
        image_data = [data['src'] for data in p_image]
        dec = {'name':name_data, 'price':price_data, 'image':image_data, 'url': url}
```

Please note with following architecture request to third party url will be sent two times. So I suppose you should refactor view and use just one form instead "**Scrape** and download".